# NLog .NET Core aspnet-user-identity always empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nlog

I've read a bunch of similarly-themed SO posts, none seem to address my issue.

My `nlog.config` resembles this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xsi:schemaLocation="NLog NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="true"
      internalLogIncludeTimestamp="true"
      internalLogFile="nlog-internal.log"
      internalLogLevel="Error">
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
  </extensions>
  <targets>
    <target xsi:type="Database"
            name="database"
            commandType="Text"
            dbProvider="Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection, Npgsql"
            connectionString="${var:appDbConnectionString}"
            commandText="Layout">
      <commandText>
        insert into "logs" ("application", "user", "level", "message", "exception", "logger")
        values (@application, @user, @level, @message, @exception, @logger);
      </commandText>
      <parameter name="@application" layout="My App" />
      <parameter name="@user" layout="${aspnet-user-identity}" />
      <parameter name="@level" layout="${level}" />
      <parameter name="@message" layout="${message}" />
      <parameter name="@exception" layout="${exception:format=tostring}" />
      <parameter name="@logger" layout="${logger}" />
    </target>
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="MyApp.*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="database" final="true" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="database" final="true"/>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Warn" writeTo="database" final="true"/>
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

... my `Startup.cs` invokes this in the `ConfigureServices()` method:

```
services.AddLogging();
```

... my `Startup.cs` invokes this in the `Configure()` method:

```
var loggerFactory = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<ILoggerFactory>();
        LogManager.LoadConfiguration("nlog.config");
        LogManager.Configuration.Variables["appDbConnectionString"] =
            config["ConnectionStrings:ApplicationContext"];
        loggerFactory.AddNLog();
```

... my `BuildWebHost(string[] args)` in my `Program.cs` has:

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
{
    return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseNLog()
        .Build();
}
```

My ClaimsPrincipal is properly filled out and configured with authenticated users, but I *cannot* get the `{aspnet-user-identity}` to be anything other than blank.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using NLog 4.5.10, NLog.Extensions.Logging 1.3.0, and NLog.Web.AspNetCore 4.7.0; these seem to be the latest libraries.

Comment: Can you try to register NLog in the same manner as described [here](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2)? Specifically with the `Startup.cs` file.

Comment: I don't see anything in that link about the Startup.cs file?

Comment: Have you for fun checked NLog Internal Logger: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-logging always a good place to start when https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SO IT TURNS OUT that NLog implements its own Service Locator when using it with IoC containers.  I needed to add a line like so:

```
app.ApplicationServices.SetupNLogServiceLocator();
```

...and magic happened.  I had to write an [issue in GitHub](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/issues/327) for it, but they responded almost instantly

Comment: Either you should configure NLog in Program.cs with UseNLog https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2#4-update-programcs or use AddNLog in Startup.cs (ASP NET Core ver1-Style). Not using both as you do in your original StackOverflow-question.

Comment: Understood... that was an artifact of just trying to figure out what was going on.

Comment: Future readers, "app" here is Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IApplicationBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

`loggerFactory.AddNLog();` is the issue.

Change your program.cs to this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder
                    .CaptureStartupErrors(true)
                    .UseIISIntegration()
                    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                    .UseStartup<Startup>()
                    .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
                    {
                        //logging.AddNLog(); //<--- Can remove (NLog.Extensions.Logging)
                    })
                    ;
            })
            .UseNLog(); // <--- Call UseNLog off of IHostBuilder (NLog.Web)
}
```

see https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-3

Answer (score 0):

When you debug, does `User.Identity.Name` resolve to anything?

I ran into this and fixed it by adding a claim with `ClaimTypes.Name` to the ClaimsPrincipal. I had all the claims I needed, but `ClaimsIdentity` was looking for a specific claim to generate the name.

Comment: Hmm... I'll investigate this.

Comment: So I checked, and User.Identity.Name is indeed filled out properly.